# Apache HTACCESS Rewrite Rule domain to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am attempting to build a .htaccess file to rewrite requests to a specific domain name (e.g. domainA.com) to a subfolder on my webserver.

The mapping should be:

```
(www.)domainA.com -> /domainA/
(www.)domainB.com -> /domainB/
and all other requests -> / (root)
```

I've gotten this far:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainA.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domainA/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domainA/$1 [L]
```

But this just results in a 404, the folder 'domainA' does certainly exist in the root folder.